# SQL query for compare the existed quantity and requested quantity

Tags: sql

Consider there is a warehouse that some quantity of each part exists in different locations and each location can have 1 to several lot ids. For example if we have 100 of product X on location A, it can be 10 boxes of product X with the quantity of 10 in each box, which is equal to 100 and each of this boxes has specific id, which is called lot id. So, every day in a plant, they need to make different parts, and for building each part, other parts will be used. If we want to build 200 of part Y, we need 200 of part X . How can I write a SQL query which shows me all the lot ids along with their locations of part X until they cover the required quantity which is 200 ? And the query is needed yo show me the lot ids based on their order. I mean I need to see the lot id number 1 before I see the lot id number 20, no matter what will be their locations.

Comment: Make it easy, and possible, to assist you: [mcve].

Comment: Please read this to learn how to ask question.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask